# How does one stop graphs from the same code from overlapping?

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, networkx

The graphs that are output from two distinct nx.draw_networkx commands seem to overlap in the console. How does one properly separate different graphs?

This feels like a silly question, but I have yet to find any solution on the web.

```py
def desenho(dados)
    edges,weights = zip(*nx.get_edge_attributes(dados,'weight').items())
    pos = nx.spring_layout(dados)
    print(nx.draw_networkx(dados, pos, node_color='purple', edgelist=edges, edge_color=weights, width=5.0, edge_cmap=plt.cm.jet), '\n')

graph_1 = desenho(data_1)
graph_2 = desenho(data_2)
```

I'd expect that each output would process and match with the empty string I put in to create some distance between them, but that isn't happening. What am I doing wrong here?

**Present output**:

[image]

**Expected output**:

[image]

I'd also appreciate suggestions on how to make the color_map a bit less extreme in its gradient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a [subplot](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) for each graph that you want to plot. For example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import networkx as nx

def desenho(dados):
    edges,weights = zip(*nx.get_edge_attributes(dados,'weight').items())
    pos = nx.spring_layout(dados)
    nx.draw_networkx(dados, pos, node_color='purple', edgelist=edges, edge_color=weights, width=5.0, edge_cmap=plt.cm.jet)


fig = plt.figure()

ax = fig.add_subplot(2,1,1) # 2,1,1 means: 2:two rows, 1: one column, 1: first plot
graph_1 = desenho(data_1)

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2,1,2) # 2,1,2 means: 2:two rows, 1: one column, 1: second plot
graph_2 = desenho(data_2)
```